# Need your help in SQL query

Tags: sql, database

There are two tables:

- **Clients** (`id, name`)
- **Order** (`id, id_client, name`), where `id_client` - foreign key.

Write a query that selects the identifier and name of the first table and the number of records in the second table, associated with them. The result should be sorted by surname in descending order.

I've tried

```
SELECT 
   Clients.id, Clients.name, count(id) 
FROM clients 
INNER JOIN Order ON Clients.id = Order.id_client 
GROUP BY 
   Clients.id, Clients.name 
ORDER BY 
   Clients.name DESC
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong?

Comment: Define "it (sic) doesn't work"

Comment: Two words: LEFT JOIN. More words: `Order` is a reserved word, and the alternative to LEFT JOIN is a scalar subquery in the SELECT.

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't work* ?!?!? Do you get an error - if so: **WHAT** error? Do you just get no results at all? The "wrong" results? If so: **WHY** are they wrong - what did you expect instead?

Comment: @Guys can we not yell, he's got 1 rep point therefore he must be a new user.  Show some courtesy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
 c.ID,
 c.Name,
 COUNT(o.ID)
FROM
 Clients c
LEFT JOIN [Order] o
ON
 o.id_client = c.id
GROUP BY
 c.ID,
 c.Name
ORDER BY
 c.Name DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Clients.id, Clients.name, count(client.id) FROM clients INNER JOIN Order on Clients.id=Order.id_client GROUP BY Clients.id, Clients.name ORDER BY Clients.name DESC

Answer (score 0):

Change `count(id)` to

`count(Clients.id)` or `count(Order.id)`

I don't know which table you need `count(id)` from. I hope you understand where the issue is.

Comment: makes no difference in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 c.ID,
 c.Name,
 COUNT(o.ID)
FROM
 Clients c,
 Order o
WHERE o.id_client = c.id
GROUP BY
 c.ID
 c.Name
```

Comment: `join` syntax is more readable, this is the old way of performing a join behind the scenes.

Comment: Plus it also suffers from not bracketing the `Order` table name.